# A number characterizing the deviation of a triangle from the regular triangle

Tags: reference-request, plane-geometry

Given a triangle $\Delta$ with sides of length $a\le b\le c$, consider the number
$$q=\frac{a^4+b^4+c^4}{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2}$$ and observe that $\frac13\le q\le\frac12$ and the extremal values of $q$ characterize some geometric properties of the triangle $\Delta$. Namely:

$\bullet$ $q=\frac13$ if and only if $a=b=c$ (which means that the triangle $\Delta$ is regular);

$\bullet$ $q=\frac12$ if and only if $c=a+b$ (which means that the triangle $\Delta$ is degenerated).

I am writing a paper (in applications of math to Electric Engineering) where the number $q$ is applied for evaluation of the deviation of a triangle (describing the quality of 3-phase electric energy) from being regular, and need to call the number $q$ somewhow (for example, *quadrofactror*), but wonder if $q$ already has some standard name. This motivates my

> **Question.** Has the number $q$ some standard name in Plane Geometry?

Comment: This is not an answer but just a comment that there is another function of the side lengths which does what you want--its minimum (zero) is taken at the degenerate cases and its maximum at the equilateral one.  It does have a name (area) and its expression as a function of $a$, $b$ and $c$ is Heron's formula.

Comment: @bathalf15320 Thank you for the comment. The area is a good function but it is not invariant under similarity transformations. So, it does not evaluate the form (and the regularity) of the triangle.

Comment: Yes. I was tacitly normalising so that the longest side has length $1$--should have made that explicit.

Comment: MSE is a right forum for such type questions.

Comment: @user64494 Probably you are right concerning MSE, but I am not a member of MSE and would not like to register there only in sake of this single question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Added to my comment above, this time taking care of my carelessness in not normalising:  one has the formula
$$\frac{16 A^2}{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2}=1-\frac{2(a^4+b^4+c^4)}{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2}
$$
which shows, at least in my book, that a normalised version of the area $A$ (more precisely of its square) does the trick.

Comment: Note that $\dfrac{4A}{a^2+b^2+c^2}$ is the tangent of the [Brocard angle $\omega$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BrocardAngle.html). Thus, $q = \left(1-\tan^2\omega\right)/2$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg This should be an (perhaps the) answer, I think.

Comment: I believe the book mentioned in the answer is idiomatic. See, for example https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/in-my-book

Comment: @asahay Ups! But at least this paper about Heron formula https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/images/upload_library/22/Ford/Kendig402-415.pdf is quite real. I then rewrite what I wanted to say to user bathhalf5320.

Comment: @bathhalf15320 Thank you very much for your answer. It was very helpful. In fact, my formulas involved $q$ in the subformula $\sqrt{3−6q}$ and now I understand what this subformula actually means: it is the normalized area of the triangle! Great! I would like to  write acknowledgement to your help. Should I write your nick bathhalf15320 or some real name will be better? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, the use of "in my book" was idiomatic--I stupidly didn't realise that in this context a literal interpretation would have been quite reasonable.  Since the equation I gave is just a rearrangement of Heron, an explicit reference isn't required. Glad to have been of assistance.

Answer (score 2):

See ["List of trianle inequalities"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_triangle_inequalities) , especially its "Side lengths" section, to this end . There is a reference   Posamentier, Alfred S. and Lehmann, Ingmar. The Secrets of Triangles, Prometheus Books, 2012., p. 261 there.

Comment: Indeed, in the mentioned paper on Wikipedia there is a similar inequality with the same lower and upper bounds: $\frac13\le \frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{(a+b+c)^2}<\frac12$. But the upper bound $\frac12$ is attainable only at triangles with two coinciding vertices. On the other hand, the upper bound $\frac12$ at my inequality is attainable at each triangle on a line.